# How can I get knockout to update a defined property?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-es5-plugin

Consider this typescript class (but I don't think Typescript is relevant to the problem, other than obscuring the underlying `defineProperty` call):

```
class Model
{
   public TeamId: number;

   constructor()
   {
        var self = this;

        ko.track(this);

        ko.getObservable(this, "TeamId").subscribe(function (newValue)
        {
            var o = ko.getObservable(self, "link");
            o.valueHasMutated();
        });
    }

    get link(): string
    {
        return `/blah/blah/team/${this.TeamId}`;
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using the mapping plugin.

The `link` property uses the current `TeamId` to make a suitable link for that team. My problem is: how do I tell knockout that when the `TeamId` property changes, so does the `link` property? I thought that the `subscribe` callback would do it, but `getObservable` returns null. I guess this is because it doesn't work with properties defined with `defineProperty`. But now I'm stuck because I want to use this syntax but can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should make link a computed.

```
ko.defineProperty(this, 'link', function () {
  return `/blah/blah/team/${this.TeamId}`;
});
```

This way it should be updated automatically since you create a dependency on TeamId.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work; when `TeamId` changes, knockout doesn't realize that `link` needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I want to use property getters/setters is use them with a private backing observable field. That way it hides the observable to the outside, but you still have access to a standard observable internally to subscribe against.

```
private _property = ko.observable('myValue');
get property(): string { 
    return this._property(); 
}
set property(value:string) {
    this._property(value);
}
```

In your case you could combine that with a computed to handle the value updating automatically, and I see now that you're using the ES5 plugin which explains the `ko.getObservable()` and `ko.track()` calls, so a computed just looks like a regular function. I can't easily test all of that, but see if this does what you want:

```
class Model
{
   public TeamId: number;

   constructor()
   {
        var self = this;    
        ko.track(this);
    }

    get link(): string
    {
        return this.getLink();
    }

    private getLink(){
        return `/blah/blah/team/${this.TeamId}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on  my current workaround, I think this will work, but it's kind of kludgy to have to make a backing function like that for every property. kind of defeats much of the purpose of *having* properties.

Comment: No argument there. You might want to open another ES5-specific question to see if there's a better way.